# how can i define custom tab in flex mobile?

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile

i want to make a custom tab in the bottom of my app like in this image:
https://lh3.ggpht.com/i4vAcSohPDq8267boxxvQqcaVrFejX1PWxm0BtCkNctyEk1u8aLGS1TocUJFDjUuTok

I am using flex 4.6

can anyone suggest any ideas?